# Getting an error when installing Gulp js

Tags: javascript, powershell, npm, gulp

I'm trying to install Gulp js on my computer.

I think it is installed but not completely because when I run `gulp -v` in powershell it returns these lines:

```
[12:43:04] CLI version 1.3.0
[12:43:04] Local version 3.9.1
```

But when I want to run `.\node-setup.cmd` it throws the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-autoprefixer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\LOBOS\FDD.WAP\gulpfile.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wouldn't be solved if I would install `gulp-autoprefixer` because afterwards it would require another module and after that another module and so on...

The solution was to deprecate the `package.json` file by changing the `react-bootstrap-table` from my version *(2.8.2)* to version `4.0.0-beta.2`. By doing so, the json file will have a version which is not depending on react-toastr.

Answer (score 1):

most likely you have  [gulp-autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer) as a dependency in the `package.json` file of your project but you did not install it locally.
try to run `npm install` from the command line and see if it fix your issue.

Comment: is it important what folder in opened when I run this command?

Comment: yes, must be the folder where the package.json file is located

Comment: I also tried running these commands before:                                    
 `npm config set @allenfang:registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`
or
`npm config set @allenfang:registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`
or
`npm config set @allenfang:registry https://replicate.npmjs.com/`